# I'm confused about this proof concerning limits and sequences:

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Here's the theorem:

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ iff for all $a_n$ such that $a_n$ converges to $a$, $f(a_n)$ converges to $L$.

I managed to prove the forwards direction, but it's the backwards direction that's confusing me. Here's the problem I ran into when I tried to prove it.

**given**: If $a_n$ converges to $a$, $f(a_n)$ converges to $L$.

**prove**: $\lim_{ x\to a}f(x) = L$.

**proof**: We know that the sequence where every term is a converges to $a$. By the given, that means that the sequence where every term is $f(a)$ converges to $L$. However, we also know that the sequence where every term is $f(a)$ converges to $f(a)$. Thus, based on the given, $f(a) = L$.

So, based on what I got, it seems that in order for the given to hold true, I would have to be given a function where $f(a) = L$, and then prove that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = a$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am sorry your proof does not work. You need to prove the limit assertion using the epsilon-delta definition. And this direction is not as easy as the forward direction. You prove it *by contradiction*. So start by negating continuity, using the epsilon-delta definition.